# Are the coefficients of a linear combination of random vectors as random?

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, random-matrices

Given are $2n$ random vectors $x_i,y_i\in\mathbb{C}^n$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$ which entries are drawn iid from some absolutely continuous distribution. Every set of $n$ different of those vectors is almost surely linearly independent. What can be said about the vector $a_i=[a_{i,1},\ldots,a_{i,n}]^\top$ which consists of the unique coefficients of the linear combination
$$y_i = \sum_{j=1}^n a_{i,j} x_j \quad\text{?}$$
Are the $a_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$ almost surely linear independent? Do you have references to the literature which say something about that?

Comment: Are you asking whether the random variables $(a_i)$ are iid? No definitely not (but they are exchangeable). Also, you said that every set of $n$ vectors from a continuous distribution is a.s. linearly independent. Is this a hypothesis? In general it's not true as the one-dimensional distribution along a line is continuous. (It is true if you say absolutely continuous distribution). To get a counter-example to your iid claim, you can consider distributions that are continuous, but a small perturbation of a discrete distribution.

Comment: So, essentially, find the distribution of $X^{-1}y$, where $X$ is obtained by stacking the $x_i$'s horizontally?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Thanks! I must confess my question was not very accurate. I changed it. In addition I specified the distribution as "absolutely". Is it actually the same as assuming $\mathbb{P}(X=x)=0$ $\forall x$ for the distribution?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I changed the question so that it should be much clearer now what I would really like to know.

Comment: @Rob Same comment: so, essentially, you want to find the distribution of the entries of $X^{-1}Y$? That is what the coefficients of that linear combinations are.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Yes! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So $A = Y X^{-1}$, where $X$ and $Y$ are the $n \times n$ matrices with these vectors as columns, and $A$ is the matrix with entries $a_{ij}$.
Almost surely, $A$ has full rank because $Y$ and $X^{-1}$ do.  Thus the rows of $A$ are almost surely linearly independent, as are the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Your conjecture that the $a_i$ are independent is incorrect.

Consider, for example, $N=2$, $x_1$ and $x_2$ and $y$ each independent uniform randoms on $(1,0)\times(0,1)$. Then, using upper indices as vector indices
$$ \begin{array}{cc}
x_i^1 = \pmatrix{1 \\ 0} \cdot x_i && x_i^2 = \pmatrix{0 \\ 1} \cdot x_i \\
y^1 = \pmatrix{1 \\ 0} \cdot y &&y^2 = \pmatrix{0 \\ 1} \cdot y \end{array}
$$
we can express the $a_i$ as
$$ a_1 = \frac{x_2^2y^1-x_1^2y^2}{x_2^2x_1^1-x_1^2x_2^1}
$$
and a similar expression for $a_2$.  Now write out the distribution of $a_1$, and the distribution of $a_1$ givven that $a_2$ is some fixed value.  You will find those distributions are not the same (in particular, the distribution for $a_1$ is broader when $a_2$ is large), so $a_1$  and $a_2$ are not iid.

Comment: Thanks and sorry that the previous version of the question was not very accurate. I changed it so that it should be much clearer now what I would really like to know.